# Is this a non portable error of a pthread C++ program

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads

I am coding for a pthread C++ program.

I got error: 
         "pthread_getunique_np" was not declared in this scope

The pthread_getunique_np  or others with "*np" are not portable.

I cannot find solutions from posts online .

I know _np means it is not a POSIX standard.

How to get around this ?  I need to include some header files or other substitutes ?

thanks

Comment: Use a different function...? Look at your wider goals and find a different solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Martin said, on many systems, you can just used the `pthread_t` of the thread as a unique identifier.  You can retrieve this with `pthread_self(3)`, which is POSIX.  You can use the function `pthread_equal(3)` to test two `pthread_t`s for equivalence.

```
pthread_t threadID = pthread_self();
if (pthread_equal(threadID, someOtherID) != 0)
    /* Branch based on being the same thread */
else
    /* Branch based on being different threads */
```

As far as I can tell, `pthread_getunique_np()` returns a unique integer ID, which is different than using a `pthread_t` as an identifier.  On many systems, the values returned from both `pthread_self(3)` andf `pthread_getunique_np()` are the same.  In fact, you *need* the `pthread_t` to obtain the unique integer.

Either way, `pthread_self(3)` is required to return the ID of the thread from which it is called, so I believe you should be able to use this portable function the way you want.

(Information about `pthread_getunique_np()` from [IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/users_23.htm))

Answer (score 0):

The `_np` suffix means ¨non-portable¨. In other words, it is not part of the POSIX standard and so not guaranteed to be available on POSIX systems.

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I need to know how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `pthread_t` as a unique identifier. I will most problably be the same as the return value of `pthread_getunique_np` anyway.